# How to grab session ID - Xpath, C#

Tags: c#, session, xpath

I'm trying to read the value of a session ID which is served up to a client page (a pin that can then be given to other users who want to join the session), which according to chrome developer tools, is located within this element:

```
<input type="text" size="18" autocomplete="off" id="idSession" name="idSession" class="lots of stuff here" title="" ">
```

So far I've been using C# and Xpath to navigate around the site successfully, for testing purposes, but I just can't get hold of the pin that is generated within  id="idSession", or by using any other identifier through Xpath. There's a bunch of jquery stuff going on in the background, but neither is it showing up there (again, the code knows about the on-screen locations in the .js files for the ID, but that's it).

I'm new to all of this so would really appreciate a nudge in the right direction, ie. what different tools I need for this, what am I missing etc. what I need to read up on.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

What about `//input[@id='idSession']/@value` to get the content

Also, including a link to a helper library for creating xpath using linq-esq syntax

```
 var xpath = CreateXpath.Where(e => e.TargetElementName == "input" &&
                              e.Attribute("id").Text == "idSession").Select(e => e.Attribute("value"));
```

http://unit-testing.net/CurrentArticle/How-to-Create-Xpath-From-Lambda-Expressions.html